# Jenkins restart error, Starting Jenkins dirname: extra operand `/proc

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to restart Jenkins, but it fails saying with the below error.  Has anyone any clue on this?

```
$ service jenkins restart
Shutting down Jenkins killproc: Empty pid file /var/run/jenkins.pid for /usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin/java
                                                                                                                                                                          done
Starting Jenkins dirname: extra operand `/proc/13265/exe'
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.
                                                                                                                                                                          failed
```

Answer (score 3):

Probabily when you restart the service jenkins does not remove his files in the /proc directory. Execute this line before start jenkins:

```
find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user jenkins -name exe -lname '*/bin/java'
```

If you have a result (as in my case) it means that there are an older /proc/XXXX dir and jenkins create another one. This is the reason why this proces fails ( in runtime there are to dirs and it causes the error)

### Resolution

**Option 1:** Try to remove the dir that appear when you execute "`find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user jenkins -name exe -lname '*/bin/java'`" command (I could not for permission reasons

**Option 2**: Modify the file /etc/init.d/jenkis, find the line that has this code:

```
JPROC=$( find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user $JENKINS_USER -name exe -lname "*/bin/java" )
```

and replace it for this one:

```
JPROC=$( find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user $JENKINS_USER -name exe -lname "*/bin/java"  | tail -1 )
```

The second option works for me. I should tell to jenkins folks this bug.